# How to correctly add a row to NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

Firstly I must note that this is my first GUI-app (XIB) in Swift, in other words I am working on and trying to learn Swift and MacOS software development. I have looked through several questions, here at Stack, as well as the Apple documentation on NSTableView, but I'm stuck.

Trying to make a simple app to read some attributes of selected files. I have a custom `NSView` where the user drags and drop in a file and it reads some attributes off it - which is ok.

```
>>> print("\(fileDataToShow)\n\(resultTable)")
Optional([["filename": "foo.jpeg", "state": "1"],["filename": "bar.jpeg", "state": "1"]])
Optional(<NSTableView: 0x101203070>)
```

The `@IBOutlet weak var resultTable: NSTableView!`, at top of the file containing the class/NSView, show that it is connected, `MainMenu.XIB—ResultTable`.

I have come up with following code, in an attempt to display the data in the NSTableView, from my custom `class View: NSView {`

```
override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    <...>
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return fileDataToShow?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
        var result:NSTableCellView
        result  = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = fileDataToShow?[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]! as! String
        return result
    }

    resultTable?.beginUpdates()
    // print(type(of:fileDataToShow)) // Optional<Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>>
    resultTable.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: fileDataToShow?.count ?? 0), withAnimation: .effectFade)    
    resultTable.reloadData()
    resultTable?.endUpdates()
}
```

Content of `fileDataToShow` is ok, but the other lines of code, `.beginUpdates()` / `.insertRows(..`, etc. doesn't seem to have any action.
As mentioned, I can't figure this out and don't know where or how to figure this... Anyone got some tips and/or pointers for me ?

I have defined all of the keys in `fileDataToShow` to correspond with the `Identifiers` in my XIB.

Hope I have managed to explain my problem in an ok way.

EDIT:
The Debug area giving following output when I run my app:
`*** Illegal NSTableView data source (<NSObject: 0x600000000b90>).  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`

EDIT2/Update: 
Thank you @vadian, but I still haven't managed to fix this, here's a little update.
Here's my whole file, `DropZone.swift`:
```

```
class DropView: NSView/*, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate*/ {
    @IBOutlet weak var resultTable: NSTableView!

    let dropZoneEnteredBackgroundColor = CGColor(red: 165/255, green: 165/255, blue: 165/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let dropZoneExitedBackgroundColor = CGColor(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1.0)//NSColor.gray.cgColor

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = dropZoneExitedBackgroundColor
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.URL,
                                 NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
    }
    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = dropZoneEnteredBackgroundColor

        return .copy
    }
    override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) {
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = dropZoneExitedBackgroundColor
    }
    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let pasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType:
            NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType")) as?
            NSArray else {return false}

        var droppedItems: [String: String] = [:]

        for path in pasteboard {
            guard let fullPath = path as? String else { return false }

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            var isDir: ObjCBool = false

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullPath, isDirectory:&isDir) {
                if isDir.boolValue {
                    // the dropped item exists and it's a directory
                    droppedItems[path as! String] = "folder"
                }
                else {
                    // file exists and it's not a directory, hence a normal file
                    droppedItems[path as! String] = "file"
                }
            }
        }
        do {
            var fileDataToShow = [[String:Any]]()

            for object in droppedItems {
                if object.value == "file" {
                    do {
                        //let fullPath = object.key
                        let attributes = try object.key.extendedAttributes()  // Array<String>
                        let filename = object.key.fileName() + "." + object.key.fileExtension()

                        fileDataToShow.append(["state": "1",
                                               "filename": filename,
                                               "metadata":removed_attributes
                        ])
                    }
                    catch  {
                        debugPrint("Error info: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                else if object.value == "folder" {
                    // TODO
                }
            }

            func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
                return fileDataToShow.count
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
                let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn?.identifier ?? NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: ""), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
                // This line could crash if there values which are not String
                cell.textField?.stringValue = fileDataToShow[row][tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue ?? ""] as! String
                return cell
            }
            let insertionIndex = fileDataToShow.count
            //debugPrint(resultTable) // Optional(<NSTableView: 0x10100ba10>)
            //debugPrint(fileDataToShow) // [["filename": "img1.jpeg", "metadata": ["com.apple.metadata..", "com.a..."], "state": "1"]]
            resultTable.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: insertionIndex), withAnimation: .effectGap)
        } // do
        return true
    }
}
```

This is now giving the following error:
`*** Canceling drag because exception 'NSTableViewException' (reason 'NSTableView error inserting/removing/moving row 2 (numberOfRows: 0).') was raised during a dragging session`

Sorry, but have had trouble with this since the last reply from @vadian, so have to ask again.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 3:
Appreciate your answers, @vadian, but I do not get this. I have places the `numberOfRows` and `tableView` function right underneath the **init** function. And implemented following code last in the do-block, in an attempt to update the table:

```
resultTable.beginUpdates()
var i = 0
for row in fileDataToShow {
    print("state:",row["state"]!) // 1
    print("filename:",row["filename"]!) // file.jpg
    print("metadata:",row["metadata"]!) // ["com.apple.metadata..", "com.a..."]
    resultTable.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: i), withAnimation: .effectFade)
    i += 1
}
resultTable.endUpdates()
```

New lines is added to the table, but they are all empty. How do I - in  any way - bind `fileDataToShow` against `resultTable.insertRows`.

If you understand my poor spelling and fussy questions :)
Swift is hard but fun to learn!

Comment: Remove resultTable.reloadData() between beginUpdates() and endUpdates()

Comment: Once again: ***The datasource / delegate methods must be on the top level in the class, not in `performDragOperation`***

Comment: Feeling sort of dumb, but can you please explain where "the top level in the class" then is ? And by "datasource / delegats" do you mean the `fileDataToShow.append([...` part of my code ?

Comment: `datasource / delegate` is `numberOfRows` and `viewFor tableColumn` and the top level is the scope within the first pair of braces (for example  `init` and `draggingEntered` is on the top level)

Comment: After your edit on 11/18: **Please (re)read my answer carefully**. First you have to insert/append an item in/to the datasource array, then insert the row at the same index(path). And once again: `Begin-/endUpdates` is pointless. If the data source array has already been populated call `reloadData()` (once).

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in the code.

- `numberOfRowsInTableView` is `numberOfRows(in tableView:` in Swift 3+.
- The datasource / delegate methods must be on the top level in the class, not in `performDragOperation`.
- You are using too many question marks.
- Don not declare the data source array as optional, declare it as empty non-optional array.

  ```
  var fileDataToShow = [[String:Any]]()
  ```

---

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return fileDataToShow.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
    let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn.identifier!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    // This line could crash if there values which are not String
    cell.textField?.stringValue = fileDataToShow[row][tableColumn.identifier!.rawValue)] as! String
    cell result
}
```

To insert a row with animation don't call `reloadData()`. Get the last index of the array, append the item to the array and insert the row.
`Begin-/endUpdates` is useless

```
let insertionIndex = fileDataToShow.count
fileDataToShow.append([:]) // append some suitable dictionary
resultTable.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: insertionIndex), withAnimation: .effectGap)
```